# How can I guarantee that I am connecting to my service and not someone else?

Tags: wcf, security, identity

I have a setup that looks like:

[image]

I am using windows authentication to encrypt the connections. The Main Service is secure, no one has access to it, so it is safe to store the username and passwords of each Node service in order to connect to them whenever they are available.

The main service sends confidential information to each WCF Node Service. Because the connection is encrypted I know is going to be hard for someone to decrypt it. **The problem that I have is how can I be sure that I am connecting to my WCF Node Service and not someone else?**

**Here is a scenario to describe my problem**
Let's say Tom is a user that is using the top left laptop on the diagram where the WCF Node Service is running. The WPF clients are administrators (bottom users on diagram) and they can perform actions on Tom's computer. Tom requires to see the content of an encrypted file. Tom does not have permission to have the password to decrypt that file; therefore, Tom then ask's the administrator to please decrypt that file for him.  The administrator will then send the password to the Main Service encrypted, the main wcf service will locate Tom's computer and execute the method `UnencryptFile(string location, string password)` on Tom's computer.

How can I prevent Tom from getting that password? If he replaces the WCF Node Service with his own replacing the method `UnencryptFile(string location, string password) ... MesageBox.Show(password)` he will be able to get the password. **In short I know it is possible to decompile a program so I don't mind for Tom to know what my program is doing. What I mind is connecting to a service that is not mine.** Also what happens if Tom debugs the WCF Node Service. Is it possible to debug an executable? If that is the case then he will be able to see the password that way.

Comment: I like your graphic by the way.  Very professional :-)

Comment: This is the problem that [**DRM**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) takes on, right?  For example how does Netflix stream the bytes of a movie to you computer, but you can't just use tcpdump to save the movie's bytes and play it later offline.  And Valve's Steam lets you download the entire contents of a video game, but if you copy those video game files to your friend's computer, they won't run.  Just giving your question some broader context (this comment is not intended to be an answer.)

Comment: @MikeClark You're correct, though I don't know of any DRM that hasn't been broken by someone.  It is effective for probably 99.9999% of users, but there's always someone out there who can break it.  Hopefully we can figure out a fool proof way, and become very rich men :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to stop Tom from getting the password.  Ultimately if Tom knows what he's doing, he can get the password in one way or another.  Some possibilities include performing a memory dump while the key is in memory, and reverse engineering the binary to save it out somewhere as you mentioned.

The "correct" way to do this is to have Tom send the file to either the admin or the Main Service, and have the service return the unencrypted contents.

The bottom line is that if you send Tom the key, no matter what you do to your client you can't stop Tom from recovering the key if he is sufficiently savvy with RE techniques.

Comment: +1 thanks you are right. What I will do is try to make the WCF Node service code hard to decompile. Then have a method in the service that looks like `int IsThisMyProgram(int code) { if (code==1) return 423; else if(code==2) return 893; etc...` Some sort of algorithm like that. I will just try to make that code hard to decompile... If I send 2 for example I know I have to get back 893 for instance.

Comment: @TonoNam That is a good suggestion, and in fact many game companies use that trick.  If you sprinkle these checks throughout your code and terminate when the check fails, it will be a nightmare for an RE.  You could also send hundreds of "keys" in which only one is the correct one.  You can then read the key many times from code and only use the "right" one.  This is called buffer smearing and game companies use it to make life hard for REs

Comment: Exactly. I will have a table with hundreds of keys. The Server will have that table and also the Nodes. Each day I can change that table as long as I change it in both the service and node.